# In Angular JS application, how do you handle the cases where there is no response from the server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Lets say I have a route set up like so:

```
$routeProvider.
     when('/myroute', {templateUrl: '/views/RouteA.html',   controller: 'AController'}).
     otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'})
```

If the server is down, when I click a link to "http://myapp.com/#/myroute" I can see that the requests to load the RouteA.html file are timing out. However, to the user, the application just sits there leaving them with no indication of a problem. I don't see any clear explanation anywhere for handling this type of non-response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Best way to tackle this is to add routeChangeError event

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function () {
   alert("there is some error");
  //do what ever you want to do again
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this cant be a hint for you...

```
 $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```